# can't get modal to display using bootstrap and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/gp277ps1/4/ Nothing happens when I click on Login, what am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" hidden="true">
            <div class="login-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="panel panel-filled">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                              test
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are missing bootstrap.js or modal.js in your fiddle. Those are necessary for the bootstrap modal to work. Check out the following page [Bootstrap JavaScript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not included bootstrap js file. include this https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js in jsfiddle.